# Populate a BaseModel using session variables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a BaseViewModel for the data needed in my layout.cshtml. I have got it successfully working although I am not happy with the way I must populate the models for the BaseViewModel:

BaseViewModel

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public MyBList B { get; set; }
    public MyCList C { get; set; }
    public MyDList D { get; set; }

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        A = false;
        B = new MyBList();
        C = new MyCList();
        D = new MyDList();
    }
}
```

Currently I am populating the data in each controller:

Model:

```
public class MyViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public List<myModel> mystuff { get; set; }
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        mystuff = new List<myModel>();
    }
}
```

Controller: (session variables are attained within the functions)

```
MyViewModel model = new MyViewModel();
model.mystuff = myfunction();
model.A = await myfunctionA();
model.B = await myfunctionB();
model.C = await myfunctionC();
model.D = await myfunctionD();
```

I would like to avoid having to put 4 lines of code in each controller.

I tried using the Model constructor but my session ID was null only on a handful of controllers:

```
public bool A { get; set; }
public MyBList B { get; set; }
public MyCList C { get; set; }
public MyDList D { get; set; }

public BaseViewModel()
{
    string sessionID = HttpContext.Current.Session.SessionID;
    A = Afunction(HttpContext.Current.Request.UserAgent);
    var Btask = Task.Run(async () => { A = await Bfunction(); });
        Btask.Wait();
    var Cttask = Task.Run(async () => { C = await Cfunction(sessionID); });
        Cttask.Wait();
    var Dtask = Task.Run(async () => { D = await Dfunction(); });
}
```

I have also tried creating a parent model in the basemodel:

```
public abstract class BaseViewModel
{
    public BaseModel model { get; set; }

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        model = new BaseModel();
    }
} 

public abstract class BaseModel
{
    public bool A { get; set; }
    public ThemeID B { get; set; }
    public CartItemThumbModel C { get; set; }
    public MenuViewModel D { get; set; }

    public BaseModel()
    {
        A = false;
        B = new MyAList();
        C = new MyBList();
        D = new MyCList();
    }
}
```

But the models I need to populate do not appear in the controller model.

Have I found the best solution of having to add 4 lines of code to every model declaration in every controller or am I missing something>

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid this approach completely and use child actions instead. It's a controller action that you can invoke from the view with the Html.Action helper:

```
@Html.Action("ActionName", "ControllerName")
```

Don't mistake if for partial views. There is one essential difference. Partial views takes parameters you provide and return some html output. Child actions can call action methods to get additional data that are not dependent on the model you provided to the view.

There is an article that explains it a little bit more: http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx/

But if you're going to start using child actions, you should also learn about View Components. The new feature of the new MVC (6/Core). Just in case :) 
http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2016/01/02/goodbye-child-actions-hello-view-components.aspx

Comment: I am replacing your suggestion with what I mention in my question. I am unable as yet to asynchronously call child actions. With this approach I can use asynchronous code. Also ... as a matter of interest ... is there any performance difference between the two?

Comment: Yes, child actions don't support asynchronous calls and yes they are always slower. But we're talking about optimized, compiled code running in memory. Maybe, if you run 50 child actions in a single view, you might see some noticeable perfomance loss. But child actions are easy to cache and the benefit of much easier maintenance of a project is more important (IMHO) than a page that loads couple milliseconds faster.